# How to jump iterator to point any other element of a list in foreach loop?

Tags: perl

I have a `foreach` loop something like

```
foreach my $ref_array (@$array1)
```

where `$array` is the result of reading an entire Excel sheet.

Inside my loop `$ref_array` gets the value of each row in the sheet. Now I want to advance `$ref_array` such that it gets the value of next row of the spreadsheet. How shall I do it in the middle of the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ideas:

First, if you always need a pair of consecutive rows then you could remember the previous row, e.g.

```
my $prev_row;
foreach my $row (@rows) {
  # Skip first row; we don't have a previous one yet
  if (!$prev_row) {
    $prev_row = $row;
    next;
  }

  # Do stuff with $prev_row and $row

  $prev_row = $row;
}
```

Second, use the normal C-style `for` loop. In that case you have indices and can actually access any required element all the time:

```
# don't iterate over the last line so not to access beyond the array
for (my $idx = 0; $idx < (scalar(@rows) - 1); $idx++) {
  my $row      = $rows[$idx];
  my $next_row = $rows[$idx + 1];
}
```

You cannot do it with a "simple" `foreach` just by using the current element only. It's not an interator, it's a reference to the current element from that list.

Comment: `$#rows` is less noisier than `scalar(@rows)-1`

Answer (score 7):

Looping from `0` to the last array index `$#$array1` would allow you to access the next row/element easily:

```
for my $index ( 0 .. $#$array1 ) {
    my ( $current, $next ) = @$array1[ $index, $index + 1 ];
    # Process the rows
}
```

Comment: Nice and very perlish. But remember to check for `$array1->[$#$array1 + 1]` which shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

A Perl 5.12.0+ alternative:

```
for ( my ( $idx, $row ) = each @$array1 ) {

    last if $idx == $#array1;         # Skip last iteration

    my $next_row = $array1->[$idx+1];
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know `each` for arrays! Again, don't forget to check if `$array->[$idx+1]` exists, it shouldn't for the last iteration.